# Disconnect FB user from using App

Tags: facebook

Can I force user to disconnect from the app? i.e. if user broke some rules, caught cheating, I not only want to remove him from our local DB, but also to disconnect him from using our app too (so it would not appear on his profile anymore).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`auth.revokeauthorization` is the answer. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/auth.revokeauthorization/

24 August 2014:

> You can do is to completely de-authorize the app making the delete
>   call. Once this is done, anyone using your app will have to go through
>   the Facebook Login process as if they were a new user.

To de-authorise a user, you need to make the following request:

```
DELETE /v2.1/me/permissions HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.facebook.com
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/permissions

Comment: I clicked the link and the page was long gong :/ When I search on Google, they are all Google+ results.

Answer (score 2):

Link in the answer from Gajus is now dead.

Answers to this question:

[Facebook deauthorize my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781015/facebook-deauthorize-my-app)

describe how to do what you want with the Graph API.