# Facebook deauthorize my app

Tags: php, facebook

Can I use Facebook PHP SDK to deauthorize my app for a particular user, basically I like to have a toggle so the user can link or unlink their facebook account to my site, I have the link part working, now just need the unlink part.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disconnect FB user from using App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406179/disconnect-fb-user-from-using-app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not using the currently supported Graph API: as currently setup there is no interface in the Graph API (or even the legacy APIs) to deauthorize an application. The user has to explicitly choose to do it themselves through the Facebook settings pages.

However...

The legacy REST api has http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/auth.revokeAuthorization/, which SOUNDS like it does what you want.

Let me know if that works for you: I'm curious.

Comment: Thanks Femi, this works exactly the way I wanted it to, the app deauthorizes. The user needs to reconfirm access to Facebook if they wish to link Facebook with my site again.

Answer (score 14):

Now Graph API has a way to do this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#permissions

> **Delete**
>
> You can de-authorize an application entirely, or just revoke a specific permission on behalf of a user by issuing an **HTTP DELETE** to **USER_ID/permissions** or **USER_ID/permissions/PERMISSION_NAME**
>   respectively. This request must be made with a valid user access_token or an app access token for the current app.

Comment: This also works: issue a `POST` request with `method=delete` in the POST parameters

Comment: notice that you can also use the apps' access token (which composed from the `APP_ID` and the `APP_SECRET` saperated with `|` )- so you don't have to have the user logged in order to do that

Comment: hey, maybe I'm missing something, but that link doesn't seem to have any way of de-authorizing an app.  Could you maybe paste an example?

Comment: They have changed the documentation, but it is still the same idea, let me edit the answer.

Comment: I tried exactly this, and now not only does the login flow tell me `You previously logged in to [appname]` but I can't even see the app in my `Apps and Websites` tab at all. Plus the Login API tells me I am `connected`. This is super confusing! Anybody else seem something like this? A phantom invisible authorization?

Answer (score 7):

Using the graph API, this works fine:

```
$ret = $this->Facebook->api('/me/permissions', 'DELETE');
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note Facebook in the process of deprecating the REST API, and have adding equivalent support to the Graph API User object for "auth.revokeAuthorization" method.

For delinking or deauthorization the user by making app call:

```
    $user_id = $this->facebook->getUser();
    $access_token=$this->facebook->getAccessToken();
    $result = $this->facebook->api(array(
            'method' => 'auth.revokeAuthorization',
            'uid' =>$user_id,
            'access_token'=>$access_token
    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the JS API an app can be deauthorized like this:

```
FB.api('/me/permissions', 'DELETE', function(res){
    if(res === true){
        console.log('app deauthorized');
    }else if(res.error){
        console.error(res.error.type + ': ' + res.error.message);
    }else{
        console.log(res);
    }
});
```

Or delete a specific permission:

```
FB.api('/me/permissions/user_birthday', 'DELETE', function(res){
    if(res === true){
        console.log('permission removed');
    }else if(res.error){
        console.error(res.error.type + ': ' + res.error.message);
    }else{
        console.log(res);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you go to Facebook Developer, then select your application, then under the "Advanced" menu there is a field called "Deauthorize Callback". Set this as a URL on your domain which is pinged when a user deauthorizes themselves, there is some documentation on the format of the data it requests [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/).

Comment: The "Deauthorize Callback" is used for people deauthorizing the application from within FB, but the question asker wants to deauthorize from within his app.