# How to revoke all Facebook permissions using Android SDK?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I'm having a problem revoking Facebook permissions using the Android SDK.

There's a case in my app where I want to revoke all permissions.  According to the Facebook documentation, you can use AsyncFacebookRunner to do this, and "if you don't specify a permission then this will de-authorize the application completely."

I'm currently doing it like this:

```
String method = "DELETE";
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("permission", "");

mAsyncRunner.request("/me/permissions", params, method, new RequestListener()
                     { ... }, null);
```

using the request signature like this:

```
void request(String graphPath, Bundle parameters, final String httpMethod,
             RequestListener listener, final Object state)
```

The onComplete() callback function seems to come back OK, but doesn't appear to have de-authorized the access token.  I'm inferring this because the next time I call facebook.authorize(), it works without pushing the user to the Facebook login page.

Any ideas what I need to change to completely de-authorize an access token?  Or is there a different/better way to do this?  Many thanks!

Comment: If you send a DELETE command to /me/permissions, the facebook app should be removed from the list of apps the user has granted (http://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications). Does the app still show up there?  If so, the DELETE command is not being processed correctly.  Using a valid access token, can you verify that the HTTP Delete command works for you in the Graph API explorer?  I ran into an issue with the C# SDK not working for me, so in a pinch I used the javascript SDK to do the delete of permissions.  Maybe the javascript SDK will work for you too.

Comment: I verified that the app still showed up even after I ran the mAsyncRunner request to delete it - so you are right that it's not working for some reason, even though the onComplete() callback returned without an exception.  I have a valid access token; how do I try the same thing using http (i.e., what's the URL that does that same thing)?

Comment: The Graph API Explorer tool is your friend  :)  http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer.  If it does work there correctly, then try doing a `GET` to the me/permissions followed immediately by doing a `DELETE`.  Sometime the SDKs get in better sync when performing the GET followed by a DELETE (seen it happen first hand).

Comment: Thanks, I tried your suggestion.  The HTTP command is "https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions/PERMISSION_NAME? access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN".  I wasn't sure what to put for PERMISSION_NAME since I am trying to deauthorize the entire app, so I tried leaving it blank (that is, "https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions/?
    access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN").  That didn't seem to delete the app either.  The response was simply: "{
  "data": [
    {
      "installed": 1
    }
  ]
}"  Any idea how to set the PERMISSION_NAME to get it to deauthorize the app entirely?

Comment: I'm confused.  Where did PERMISSION_NAME come from?  To de-auth the app, you don't seen a PERMISSION_NAME.  Since you cannot de-auth the app from the explorer tool, I suggest you ensure you're using a valid ACCESS TOKEN.

Comment: You're correct.  I am not using any permissions to deauthorize the app programmatically.  But I was trying your suggestion of trying to replicate the problem from an HTTP string.  The documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ only says how to form the HTTP string if you want to delete certain permissions, which is where the PERMISSION_NAME field came up.  I want to try your suggestion to deauthorize using HTTP, but can't figure out the corresponding HTTP string.  Any idea - hope that clarifies it.  Thx.

Comment: Thanks a lot friends. above suggestion worked for me. But there is one problem after it. I am requesting email and birthday permission for user during login. Once user logout (on logout i deauthorize the permissions), user tries to login again, it is not returning the email and bday of user. I am passing permission for it and still not  returning it. Any idea why it is not authorizing again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears from this post: [Facebook deauthorize my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781015/facebook-deauthorize-my-app) and others that it's not possible to deauthorize an application programmatically.  Unfortunately, the call above returns successfully to onCreate() but does nothing to deauth/delete the app for the user.

Bottom line: It looks like the only way to deauth an app is for the user to do it directly in Facebook.  If anyone knows differently, please say so - but otherwise, don't waste your time trying!  Thanks.

Comment: This answer is no longer correct, delete on /me/permissions does work as posted elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

For anybody looking to do this in later versions of the SDK/Graph API - It appears the correct way to do this now is as shown here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/permissions/

```
new Request(
   session,
    "/me/permissions/{permission-to-revoke}",
    null,
    HttpMethod.DELETE,
    new Request.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

Leaving the `/{permission-to-revoke}` off of the second parameter will revoke all the permissions

Comment: Will it delete the application from FB as well?

Comment: I used successfully the GraphAPI. It looks similar to your code:

GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newDeleteObjectRequest(yourToken, "/" + yourUserId + "/permissions", new GraphRequest.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {
              
            }
        });
        request.executeAsync();

Answer (score 3):

You can delete the entire application (not only permissions) from users Facebook account using latest SDK (mine is 4.1.1)

```
void deleteFacebookApplication(){
    new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/me/permissions", null, HttpMethod.DELETE, new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            boolean isSuccess = false;
            try {
                isSuccess = response.getJSONObject().getBoolean("success");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (isSuccess && response.getError()==null){
                // Application deleted from Facebook account
            }

        }
    }).executeAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the code suggested in the question and it completely de-authorized my test application. Tested it several times and it worked every each one of them.

This is also the code suggested in the official facebook documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/ - Step 7