# Make Android app forget Facebook login

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook

I have integrated Facebook login in my Android app. At first it asked for permissions (App would like to access your public profile and email address...) and logged me in. I want to test this again but no matter what I do, when I click the Login with Facebook button in my app, it logs me in.

I tried uninstalling my app, clearing cache and data of the Facebook as well. I know this is the standard behaviour, but I want Facebook to ask for permission again when I login with Facebook in my app so I could simulate and make sure that it will work when I publish the app on Google Play. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These settings are saved for each user. You can't revoke the permissions from anyone meaning the users need to deauthorize your app themselves.

On Facebook or in the Facebook app go into Settings -> Account settings -> Apps (colorful box icon) -> Logged in with Facebook. Here find your app, click on it and click Remove app.

This will revoke the permissions you gave the app with your Facebook user and next time you log in with Facebook in your app it will ask for permissions.

Comment: Perfect!! Works like charm!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Facebook SDK, you can just log out by calling `LoginManager.getInstance().logout()` methods, in `onStop()` method of your app. They closing current session, so user must login again to your app.

**EDIT**

If you want ask again for permission, you should ask again for it =)
Following the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/permissions#permissions-rerequest):
Just get the current permissions
`Session.getActiveSession().getPermissions();`
And request them again by creating `Session.NewPermissionsRequest`

```
Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, CURRENT_PERMISSION_ARRAY);
session.requestNewReadPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
```

Comment: This will not force the app ask for the permissions again.

Comment: I will try it a bit later but looks interesting. Anyway my goal is to completely make the application forget that I have ever logged in with facebook. I suppose the facebook app (that I made on developer.facebook.com) does not store all the phones that used facebook at least once and it is stored somewhere on the phone, but a few hours after looking after this I am getting confused.

Comment: Yes, the session are stores in the device, by SDK.
Maybe you should try to use both methods - closing and clear the session, and trying to request new permissions. It will looks like log-out function.

Comment: `closeAndClearTokenInformation()` is now `LoginManager.getInstance().logout()`

Answer (score 1):

You can revoke access given to a particular app by going to facebook.com -> Settings --> App, then edit whatever you want.

To do it Programmatically you can check out this link
[Revoke FB Permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584593/how-to-revoke-all-facebook-permissions-using-android-sdk)

Comment: And yup for the above method you have to login first to FB with the same FB id on which permissions has been granted..!!

Comment: I will try it  a bit later. The only thing I found here is "Client OAuth Login" which says: Enables the OAuth client login flow. Do you think it is what I am looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I got this same problem and try almost everything until I realize that I was using Chrome browser to login once in Facebook and my application founds my login information from browser cache. So open up browser and go to facebook.com it immediately logs me in, I press log out and my app works as it should.. :)

Comment: I think the question is more about updating the Facebook settings for the app rather than just the Facebook login

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me!