# Android Facebook login - How to rerequest Email permission when rejected

Tags: facebook, email, authentication, sdk, permissions

I googled nearly half a day and I couldnt find any example which can solve this issue. The case is this. User in first time login sees email request and rejects it. Next time when he logs in then it says "you have already authorized" It does not ask again for email request because it was rejected.
I dont want the user to go to settings and change it. Isnt there any way to ask this permission again? 
Please helppp

```
private UiLifecycleHelper uihelper;  
Session mCurrentSession;
void showMsg(String string)
   {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }


 /*  private Session.StatusCallback callback =new Session.StatusCallback() 
     {

        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) 
        {

            onSessionStateChange(session,state,exception);
        }
    };*/


     void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) 
     {
        if (state.isOpened()) 
        {
            Log.i("facebook", "Logged in...");
            Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() 
            {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) 
                {

                    if(user!=null)
                    {
                      showMsg(user.getName());
                      showMsg(user.getProperty("email")+"");
                      showMsg(user.getProperty("gender")+"");
                      showMsg(user.getId()+"");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        showMsg("its null");
                        showMsg(response.getError().getErrorMessage());
                    }
                }
            }).executeAsync();

        } 
        else if (state.isClosed()) 
        {
            Log.i("facebook", "Logged out...");
        }
    }


@Override
protected void onResume() {     
    super.onResume();
//  uihelper.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
//uihelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
//  uihelper.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
//  uihelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
//  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
//uihelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);

  if (mCurrentSession.isOpened()) {
    Request.newMeRequest(mCurrentSession, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

          // callback after Graph API response with user object
          @Override
          public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
              Log.w("myConsultant", user.getId() + " " + user.getName() + " " + user.getInnerJSONObject());
          }
        });
    }

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     signInWithFacebook();
// uihelper =new UiLifecycleHelper(this,callback);  
// uihelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
/*  
    ArrayList<String> permission =new ArrayList<String>();
    permission.add("email");
    permission.add("public_profile");
    permission.add("user_friends");     

    LoginButton btn=(LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.fbbtn);
    btn.setPublishPermissions(permission); 

    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "com.something.examp", 
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

*/

```
}
/*public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    }*/
private void signInWithFacebook() {

    SessionTracker  mSessionTracker = new SessionTracker(getBaseContext(), new Session.StatusCallback() {

        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        }
    }, null, false);

    String applicationId = Utility.getMetadataApplicationId(getBaseContext());
    mCurrentSession = mSessionTracker.getSession();

    if (mCurrentSession == null || mCurrentSession.getState().isClosed()) {
        mSessionTracker.setSession(null);
        Session session = new Session.Builder(getBaseContext()).setApplicationId(applicationId).build();
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        mCurrentSession = session;
    }

    if (!mCurrentSession.isOpened()) {
        Session.OpenRequest openRequest = null;
        openRequest = new Session.OpenRequest(LoginMain.this);

        if (openRequest != null) {
            openRequest.setDefaultAudience(SessionDefaultAudience.FRIENDS);
            openRequest.setPermissions(Arrays.asList( "email"));
            openRequest.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SSO_WITH_FALLBACK);

            mCurrentSession.openForRead(openRequest);
        }
    }else {
        Request.newMeRequest(mCurrentSession, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
              @Override
              public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                  Log.w("myConsultant", user.getId() + " " + user.getName() + " " + user.getInnerJSONObject());
              }
            });
    }
}
```

UPDATE 1:

In HelloFacebookSample (it comes with sdk  3.8) when I change private static final String PERMISSION = "email"; it will ask me even though I say Not now for the permission.

However when I change to my app id it doesnt ask anymore. It just asks one time and thats it.

My app id is not reviewed BUT I just want email information which doesnt require any extra review. CAN SOMEONE HELP ME

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I found a solution even though it cost me money I will share with all.

You have to check for permissions in your login then if you find that this person is not allowing email you have to revoke all the permissions. In previous ones they did also like that
[How to revoke all Facebook permissions using Android SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584593/how-to-revoke-all-facebook-permissions-using-android-sdk)

```
  Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
            new Request(session, "me/permissions", null, HttpMethod.DELETE,
                    new Request.Callback() {
                        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                            Log.e("Complete", response.toString());
                            Toast.makeText(c.getApplicationContext(), "Erase Completely",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                          //  postStatusUpdate();
                        }
                    }).executeAsync();
```

Answer (score 3):

Updated for SDK v4.1+

```
Set<String> permissions = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getPermissions();
if(permissions.contains("email")) {
    // Continue your stuff.
} else {
    GraphRequest request = new GraphRequest(
        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
        "/me/permissions", null, HttpMethod.DELETE,
        new GraphRequest.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {
               LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
               Toast.makeText(context, "Email permission is needed. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    );
    request.executeAsync();
}
```