# Facebook app logout

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I have used a very simple code for my php app, which actually does nothing but displays the user ID. I have not considered any security measures because I am just testing this app.

I am allowing the user to login clicking on a link and after allowing access to my app, the user is redirected to the home page and his/her user ID is displayed.

however, the logout url I have included destroys the users facebook session.

I want something different . I want to revoke the access of that app from that user when the user clicks on Logout. Is it possible?

```
<?php

require './src/facebook.php';

$config = array();
$config['appId'] = '542738299083506';
$config['secret'] = '********************************';
$config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional

$facebook = new Facebook($config);

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope' => 'publish_stream,publish_actions'
));


?>
<a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>" target="_TOP">Login With Facebook</a>
<?php

$user = $facebook->getUser();

print_r($user);

$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();

?>

<a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>" target="_TOP">Logout</a>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781015/facebook-deauthorize-my-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like this...

```
$facebook->api('/me/permissions', 'DELETE');
```

Calling this will revoke the app permissions for the current user.  If you want to revoke from another user replace `me` with the profile id.

> You can de-authorize an application or revoke a specific extended permissions on behalf of >a user by issuing an HTTP DELETE request to PROFILE_ID/permissions with a user access_token >for that app.
>
> Parameter Description Type Required permission The permission you wish to revoke. If you >don't specify a permission then this will de-authorize the application completely. string >no You get the following result.
>
> Description Type True if the delete succeeded and error otherwise. boolean

Comment: `$facebook->api('/me/permissions', 'DELETE');` I used it and it gave me some uncaught exception.
`try {
  $facebook->api('/me/permissions', 'DELETE');
 } catch (Exception $e) {
  
 }
 Header("location: index.php");`
So I used it in this manner. Is this Ok to use a empty catch block.