# Facebook logout not working properly Titanium

Tags: facebook, http, facebook-graph-api, titanium

I am using Ti SDK 5.1.0. My development platform is iOS. My iOS version 8.1. Facebook SDK version is 4.0.5.
My Facebook logout functionality is not working properly. User authorize my app by logging in through Safari. Login functionality is working properly. For logging out user click logout button. And i execute below code for logging out.

```
function logoutFb() {
        fb.addEventListener('logout', function(e) {
            var client = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
            client.clearCookies('https://m.facebook.com');
            client.clearCookies('http://m.facebook.com');
            client.clearCookies('https://login.facebook.com');
            fb.uid = null;
            fb.accessToken = null;
        });
        fb.logout();
    };
```

After execution of above function i check `fb.loggedin` property which shows false. When user tries to login again. Safari does not ask for username,password but instead shows that "You have already authorized this app". What's the solution for problem so that after logging out the user has to provide username,password again. And one more thing after manually  logging out from Facebook in Safari i.e. by opening Facebook.com and logout. My above Facebook logout event-listener never executes.

Answer (score 0):

When you logout from FB in the app it destroys the current session but does not rollback the permissions the user gave the app. The user can do that via https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications or in the app you can use one of the graph requests discussed here: [Facebook deauthorize my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781015/facebook-deauthorize-my-app)

Comment: I tried the suggestions people have posted on link you gave. But no luck in executing **/me/permissions** or **uid/permissions** through facebookGraphAPI with DELETE request. My app always crash. 'fb.requestWithGraphPath("/me/permissions", "DELETE", function(res) {});'

Comment: What's the crashlog? You do call this graph before logging out I assume?

Comment: I am executing it standalone without fb.logout()